# cakePHP3 Burzum/User-Tools can't login

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I create a new cakePHP3 Project and install the Plugin: Burzum/User-Tools.

Everythink work fine, like register or Reset Password. But I can't login. Everytime I get the error: **Invalid login credentials!** I don't know why I can't login.

In addition I can view the /Users without Login and he don't insert "created - Datetime" in my Database

Here is my Code:

**Controller/UsersController.php**

```
class UsersController extends AppController{

public function initialize() {
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Burzum/UserTools.UserTool');
}

  public function beforeRender(Event $event) {
    $this->set('userData', $this->Auth->user());
}
}
```

**View/AppView.php**

```
namespace App\View;
use Cake\View\View;

class AppView extends View
{
    public function initialize() {
      parent::initialize();
      $this->loadHelper('Burzum/UserTools.Auth');
    }
}
```

[My datatable (mySQL)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqK0l.png)

[And my hashed password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weTVo.png)

Comment: "But I can't login. " how looks your passwords columns?

Comment: added two screenshots. One of my table and one of the hashed password

Comment: Well, it should be obvious that "But I can't login" won't be any help in solving the problem. I assume that you haven't configured the Auth component correctly. The plugin will attempt to load it if you haven't configured it but just with default that probably won't match existing data if you have any. Show your auth config from the AppController.